# Non-blocking user input in Kademlia/Twisted

Tags: python, io, twisted, kademlia

I use the [Kademlia](https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia) library to create a P2P network. Once the node joined the network, I want the user to be able to ask in the command line to get a key or put a tuple in the network.

My problem is that I/O are blocking the connexion which mean that the node will be disconnected from the network while the user is typing is input.

My code is the following :

```
from kademlia.network import Server
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
import sys

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

def usi(server):
    key = str(raw_input())
    value = str(raw_input())
    print("Putting data: (" + key + ";" + value + ")")
    server.set(key, value).addCallback(done)

def done(res):
    print "Key put:"
    print res

def boostrapDone(found, server, key):
    if len(found) == 0:
        print 'could not bootstrap'
        reactor.stop()
    server.set(key, 'value').addCallback(done)

srv = Server()
srv.saveStateRegularly('out.pik')
srv.listen(8887)
srv.bootstrap([('127.0.0.1', 8888)]).addCallback(boostrapDone, srv, 'test')
loop = LoopingCall(usi, srv)
loop.start(2)
reactor.run()
```

I've read several SO questions about this problem and I've read the stdin.py and stdio.py example from [twisted example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/) and it seems like I need to use StandardIO on the twisted protocol. But Kademlia use a high-level class (Server) to simplify the use of the protocol and I don't know if I can get non-blocking I/O without modifying the library.

EDIT:
I tried to use `reactor.callInThread` that way :

```
def usi(server):
    while True:
        key = str(raw_input())
        value = str(raw_input())
        print("Putting data: (" + key + ";" + value + ")")
        server.set(key, value).addCallback(done)

def done(res):
    print "Key put:"
    print res

def boostrapDone(found, server, key):
    if len(found) == 0:
        print 'could not bootstrap'
        reactor.stop()
    server.set(key, 'value').addCallback(done)

srv = Server()
srv.saveStateRegularly('out.pik')
srv.listen(8887)
srv.bootstrap([('127.0.0.1', 8888)]).addCallback(boostrapDone, srv, 'test')
reactor.callInThread(usi, srv)
reactor.run()
```

It seem to work but sometime the node can't get a response from the other nodes, and it remove them from his bucket making him unable to put the tuple in the network, so I guess I'm still doing something wrong.
(I manage to reproduce the bug, it seem to happen when user input take more than 5 seconds, kademlia is the unable to receive the response from the other node and timeout them)